# Overloaded function not returning class of the proper type when matching against different input types (typescript)

Tags: javascript, typescript, types, typescript-typings, typescript-generics

I'm writing a small typescript library that wraps base primitives, but can't seem to get the overloaded function generic types to work with objects ({K:V})

[Here is a minimal TS playground example with the error](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/LAKApgHgDg9gTgFwAQGMA2BDAzlpB1ODKKMOAHgBUA%20JAb1CSQDcM0AuJCgbgdRgDssCOAFcUCeAAoW7TgEo6vRggAWASywA6GUgC8zVjxCMAvrwDmYBADVWIsJLkcKi44yRwrIuPySqN2oa8Zm4A9KFIKmBoJHBIAGYi-OJqAgnwqFEoANZq-OZIavGFyBpIGEgA7oTEpLxCGAhqKIVYBESx0qwcGPwAnk4GaK34NbFkSdn8MJX8NPRujEVIXcN5DclgMMXttXAKC%207ungjevsL2RkcmSNFYYK5HjCdnCaz3V%204hpqAhoJCwRCoTA4JAAIWwYAAwiCsJR5rwZPZnJ8UAIhKJxFIAPpIsDOJAAH1GHVI8IOSkKxUku1img0tNIklxdjAcgpIEpynUWjxeiQLLQ9k0lhsrMclJMdwehye-l5rP5gvskuCv1A-2g8GQ6GwuAA8gAjABWYHEML1ZF4AGlbhAEGB%20AATXAYvIFYn8EQAW0NpCJSCwfV9MDQABpeNYI24XJAHc7cLLGABtbJgPqFXzWgC6HGsnxu%20iTSFT6czSBzeYLoBoccdLvBkItOHhj0D0TNCEkab6HGtHKOaMEyH4YEqRtw%20lHlRJe0k8sCQrApb62bkn2eXh8SEs-GbWEk04n67VID%20IFCACokAAxJIpNL6pikNAwDANy%20hDUXiLVUnkGATU7GgED6EhNUBZBEmSJo0l3fd4UkRFWQJOsEzbFMe3LHttk4XNM3if181PI4AH5Z3GahKQ4UdnzgUBBiNU1zVhMgcOKCgw04FdcIobMuOoIxQHCJAoDgNRvTUJpnz8MCHmwcpUEaFAVAAWlYNAIO1BJ71g3x4NY6hVmReQOAhe4EME78ROgh9fCdMB4jyKTUn4LSgVsvSd0dSyqGZPFnAHJA0CsYEsE%20ZZ5zk3DlQeXR4qQAAiQDmIQRKkAAMgygU%20QAQgSr00DQILGHQSckGnJAmM7BD2M4ASeI47M-Ni9ckBEm8MhSzssGCW40HuDCwv5SrzOhQyWrxOQSI8LdfDKoxzxEgBlCSoBCpBDUhO0MG9dawFAIchAqn1935Ay9UkABGNqRLGhCvV9UgqGEiJ5SqeBslwSQ-1qJ0kG68RppAI7kBSid9wAJnOnzYUPMcKKZWhyg4Wg8lHOAOCuyGbhMdkuHaiJqpYy0AHIMFJrjHr9OAuORjAaJ9GmkBMF7OR-PweSQJ0YDAXBpmQSpPpWABJUmZPfBz-tUB5QJISI8mQBSKkqDAMwkBXzBUNA1C15AZaQSSsG9ZSomluTNGB0H2xC8QwCdEWHW9DhiYQBDSfR0hKZOp64BofRwcNLAoc0e5ba7RKMES26Inu1jGXINH%20AxxnfdZtmRJFu0SHEF2gJJlsPeTr2qaZ57vyAA). I've tried to simplify as much as I could while still showing the issue.

There are three classes:

1. `Wrapper<T>`
2. `BaseClass<T>`
3. `ObjectClass<K, V>`

I'm trying to create a function `genClass`, which can take in either `T` or `Wrapper<T>`, and return a `BaseClass<T>` if it is not an object with K/V pairs, or an `ObjectClass<K, V>` if it is an object (or a `Wrapper<object>`.

The `ObjectClass` has a `select(key: K)` function, which continues to return either a `BaseClass` or an `ObjectClass` for the value V at that key.

These are the wrapper/base classes (simplified, just wraps the value and nothing else)

```
export class Wrapper<T> {
  val: T;
  constructor(val: T) {
    this.val = val;
  }
  getValue(): T {
    return this.val;
  }
  // helper function for checking if it is a wrapper
  static isWrapper(val: any): val is Wrapper<unknown> {
    if (val instanceof Wrapper) {
      return true;
    } else {
      return false;
    }
  }
}

export class BaseClass<T> {
  value: T;
  constructor(_value: T | Wrapper<T>) {
    if (Wrapper.isWrapper(_value)) {

      this.value = _value.getValue()
    }else {
      this.value = _value
    }
  }
}
```

This is the `ObjectClass`, with the `select` function:

```
export class ObjectClass<
  K extends string | number | symbol,
  V,
  T extends {
    [key in K]: V;
  } = {
    [key in K]: V;
  }
> extends BaseClass<T> {
  select(key: K) {
    const newObs = new Wrapper(this.value[key]);
    return Class(newObs);
  }
}
```

and this is `genClass`, with the corresponding overloads:

```
// wrapper<object> type
export function genClass<T>(
  value: T extends {
    [key in keyof T]: infer V;
  }
    ? Wrapper<T>
    : never
): ObjectClass<keyof T, T[keyof T], T>;

// primitive type as a catch-all
export function genClass<T>(value: T): BaseClass<T>;

// function definition
export function genClass<T>(_value: T) {
  let cls;
  if (typeof _value === "object" && _value !== null) {
    cls = new ObjectClass<keyof T, T[keyof T]>(_value); // For objects
  } else {
    cls = new BaseClass<T>(_value)
  }
  return cls;
}
```

This is the sample code I'm running that gives unexpected results:

```
// Simple base example
const numClass = genClass(1); // BaseClass<number>

// this also works (wrapped object)
const objObsClass2 = genClass(new Wrapper({ a: {inner: 12} })); // ObjectClass<'a', number, { a: number }>

// this does not work (I've added the type hint as a way to highlight the mismatched type.)
const selectedItem: ObjectClass<'inner', number> = objObsClass2.select("a"); // BaseClass<Wrapper<{inner: number}>>
// I expect: ObjectClass<'inner', number>
```

There seems to be an issue with the `select` not properly mapping to the overloaded function recognizing that T[K] is an object, but I'm struggling to understand why...

Anyone have an idea on what's going on?

Comment: You can't call multiple overloads in **a single line**. You need either `if (Array.isArray(v)) retrun Class(v) else if (typeof v === 'string) return Class(v)` to split overloads or `type AnyClass<T> = T extends any[] ? A<T> : T extends string? S<T> : ...`

Comment: You know what, this seems like a very advansed task, look for libraries that implement this to check how the do it, and check if there's https://github.com/type-challenges/type-challenges for the thing

Comment: Overloads are really bad at generalizing. You'll have to overload `select()` manually, or change to generic conditional types instead of overloads.  Note that this example has at least 6 call signatures, which really isn't *minimal* in the way I'd expect a [mre] to be.  If you can cut down the number of call signatures (honestly I imagine 2 signatures to be the most reasonable number for example code, maybe 3) I'll take another look and show how I'd go about changing it.  Otherwise, good luck!

Comment: Thank you @jcalz! Sorry for the compelxity. I've simplified the example further - It's now two overloads (one of which is just the base case), and I've removed most of the other classes, apart from the Wrapper and the Base class. Is that minimal enough? 

I wasn't sure how to overload `select()`, because I think I need to specify the return type based on the type of `V`, but the function only takes in an input of type K? When I tried conditional return types, it kept saying it wasn't compatible (i'm guessing because of the `genClass` signature). Do you have pointers on what I can do there?

Comment: Frankly, `T extends { [key in keyof T]: infer V; } ? Wrapper<T> : never` is bizarre; are you just trying to say `Wrapper<T>`?  Maybe `T` should just be constrained to `object` in that case?  And `ObjectClass<K, V, T>` seems like it has no more information than just `T` and I can't imagine why it isn't just `ObjectClass<T>`. Like, given this example code I'd probably write [something like this](https://tsplay.dev/m3VByN) but I don't know if that's what you're going for.  You can overload `select` instead of using a generic conditional type, but I am having trouble seeing through the weirdness.